# Function/loops issue

Tags: r, function, plyr

As part of my work I am writing quite a complex piece of code. It's been a pain for quite some time and I'm starting to make useless mistakes. So I have tried to simplify my issue down to an incredibly basic piece of code instead and still got the mistakes. Could anyone please explain what the error is and how to fix it? Thank you!

(The data frame 'my files' is at the bottom)

```
library(plyr)
setwd("J:/R/Loops")

funct <- function(x,v) 
  (x^2) + (v^2)

myfiles <- read.csv("myfiles.csv", header=TRUE)
funct(myfiles)
```

> Error in funct(myfiles) : argument "v" is missing, with no default

```
lapply(myfiles, funct)
```

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : argument "v" is missing, with no default

Data

```
myfiles <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "x  v
1  7
2  8
3  9
4 10
5 11
6 12")
```

Comment: `funct(myfiles$x, myfiles$v)`?

Comment: or `do.call(funct, myfiles)`

Comment: or `with(myfileds, funct(x,v))`? It's not clear what your expected output is. What two arguments are you attempting to pass to your function?

Comment: I was really trying to make use of lapply, as I want to go on to do iterations of different files. The options there do work but don't resolve the lapply (I think my head is a bit fried today)

Comment: you can get lapply to work, but it is not really the right tool for this since you need multiple arguments passed simultaneously to `funct`

Comment: so essentially, my oversimplification to see if I can get to grips with lapply has simplified it TOO much! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `?mapply`

```
mapply(funct,myfiles$x, myfiles$v)
[1]  50  68  90 116 146 180
```